# Equivalent of readUIntLE in Golang?

Tags: node.js, go

I need to read X (for example, 3) bytes at position Y in the buffer.

In Node.js, I'm doing this by using the Buffer class and the readUIntLE function.

For example: `readUIntLE(position, 3)`.

What is the equivalent of that process in Golang?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a byte array it's simply `buffer[3]`.

Comment: @inf can you please provide an example?

Comment: buffer := []byte("asdf"); log.Println(buffer[2]);

Comment: `readUIntLE(position, 3)` doesn't "read a byte", it reads *3* bytes at `position` in the buffer and converts those bytes to an unsigned 24-bit integer (little endian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func readUIntLE(buf []byte, offset, byteLength int) uint64 {
    var n uint64
    buf = buf[offset : offset+byteLength]
    if len(buf) > 8 {
        buf = buf[:8]
    }
    for i, b := range buf {
        n += uint64(b) << uint(8*i)
    }
    return n
}

func main() {
    buf := []byte{2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 255}
    fmt.Println(buf)
    fmt.Println(readUIntLE(buf, 0, 4))
    fmt.Println(readUIntLE(buf, 0, len(buf)))
    fmt.Println(readUIntLE(buf, len(buf)-1, 1))
}
```

Output:

```
[2 4 8 16 32 64 128 255]
268960770
18410785783142679554
255
```